# How to add paragraph at the end of 15th page of word document using wordprocessing document c#

Tags: c#, ms-office, openxml-sdk

I used WordprocessingDocument to add the paragraph at the end of a word after the last paragraph, but I need to add this paragraph at the end of the 15th page in a word document.

Below is my code adding the paragraph at the end of the document:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument wDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(ms, true))
{
    gjenerimi = randomstring(14);
    var body = wDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
    var lastParagraf = body.Elements<Paragraph>().LastOrDefault();
    var run = new Run();

    run.AppendChild(new Text(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " , "));
    run.AppendChild(new Text(gjenerimi + " , "));
    run.AppendChild(new Text(merreshifren()));

    lastParagraf.AppendChild(run);
}
```

Comment: Please describe what's not working with the code you've shown. What are you expecting and what is the result? What is your question?

Comment: For starters your going to have to check pages.

Comment: I want the paragraph to be added in the end of the page above the last page of document not at the end of document as it is displaying now.

Comment: Okay then update your question

Comment: Working in the Open XML file it's impossible to know where any page ends. Word dynamically lays out the pages when the document is opened and edited - this information is not saved in the closed document. You can only be sure of where a page breaks if a manual break has been inserted. If that's not the case in your document(s) then you can achieve this only using "the interop" when the document is opened in the Word application. (And even then it's only a "shapshot" as further editing could change that.)

Comment: Hello Cindy. How can I use Interop for adding the paragraph at the end of the 15th page?

Comment: is the answer working?

Answer (score 1):

From your comment, you need to add a paragraph at the last page, not at the end of the page.

To achieve this you need to Append a new `Paragraph` to your `Body` then create `Run` from that `Paragraph` object, then Append `Text` on the `Run` object.

**Example**

```
Body body = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
Paragraph para = body.AppendChild(new Paragraph());
Run run = para.AppendChild(new Run());
run.AppendChild(new Text("This is my text"));
wordprocessingDocument.Close();
```

> **Update** (according to the request by question author in the comment section)

If you want to add text before the last paragraph, kindly follow the steps below.

```
Body body = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
List<Paragraph> paragraphs = body.OfType<Paragraph>()
    .Where(p => p.InnerText != "")
    .ToList();
if(paragraphs.Count > 1)
{
    Paragraph beforeLast = paragraphs[paragraphs.Count - 2];
    Run run = beforeLast.AppendChild(new Run());
    run.AppendChild(new Break()); //Line Break
    run.AppendChild(new Text("This is my text paragraph, before the last one new"));
    run.AppendChild(new Break());
}
```

Comment: My word document has 16 pages.I need to add the paragraph at the end of the 15th page.I added the paragraph at the end of the document, but I don't need that.

Comment: in that case, you can count page breaks between paragraphs. But we can't guarantee that every page contains page break. So its impossible to add after a page. Sorry!!

Comment: var lastParagraf = body.Elements<Paragraph>().LastOrDefault(); This line tells where to add the paragraph. Is there any way to tell the paragraph to be added at the 15th page or before the last paragraph in the last page of the document?

Comment: you can add before the last paragraph. I'll update the Code.

Comment: update the question, so others can find it useful. Thanks.